# Google Maps V3 - Remove all Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want with google maps v3 that if you zoom-in higher than 15 the map show the marker locations but when you zoom-out i want to hide the markers. I can't find any function to do this. Nothing has worked for me so far.

So this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 15,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.429236, 6.281255),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            setMarkers(map, points);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function()
{
                        if (map.getZoom() > 15) {
                                setMarkers(map, points);
                        } else {
                                hideMarkers(map, points);

                        }
                           }); 

        }


        var points = [
            ['Location 1', 52.420891, 6.280204],
            ['Location 2', 52.420125, 6.279131],
            ['Location 3', 52.420125, 6.240125]
        ];


        function setMarkers(map, locations) {
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/map/beachflag.png',
            new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
            var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/map/beachflag_shadow.png',
            new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
            var shape = {
                coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var point = locations[i];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                shadow: shadow,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: point[0]
                });
            }
        }

        function hideMarkers(map, locations) {
            /* Remove All Markers */


            console.log("Remove All Markers");
        }
            </script>
```

Please can anybody help me whith this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified your code. I am keeping the reference of all markers in an array. and inside hideMarkers i am setting their map as null to remove them from map.

```
 function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 15,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(52.429236, 6.281255),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var markers = setMarkers(map, access_points);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            if (map.getZoom() > 15) {
                setMarkers(map, access_points);
            }
            else {
                hideMarkers(map, access_points, markers);

            }
        });

    }

    var access_points = [ [ 'Location 1', 52.420891, 6.280204 ], [ 'Location 2', 52.420125, 6.279131 ], [ 'Location 3', 52.420125, 6.240125 ] ];

    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var markers= [];
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/map/beachflag.png', new google.maps.Size(20, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0,
                32));
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/map/beachflag_shadow.png', new google.maps.Size(37, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
        var shape = {
            coord : [ 1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1 ],
            type : 'poly'
        };

        for ( var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var access_point = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(access_point[1], access_point[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : myLatLng,
                map : map,
                shadow : shadow,
                icon : image,
                shape : shape,
                title : access_point[0],
                zIndex : access_point[3]
            }); 
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        return markers;
    }

    function hideMarkers(map, locations, markers) {
        /* Remove All Markers */
        while(markers.length){
            markers.pop().setMap(null);
        }

        console.log("Remove All Markers");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to modify your code slightly, so that your markers are contained in an array that's accessible to both the `setMarkers` and `hideMarkers` functions. You can then use the `setMap` method of the [`Marker` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) to add/remove the marker from your map (pass `null` to `setMap` to remove the marker from the map):

```
var markers = [];

function createMarkers(/* some args */) {
    // Create your markers, and add each one to the `markers` array
}

function setMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(yourMap); //Add the marker to the map
    }
}

function hideMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null); //Remove the marker from the map
    }
}
```

This approach also means that you don't recreate all your `Marker` instances every time you want to show them.