# Remove Markers on Option Change Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to clear/remove all previous markers on option change. I've tried searching the the Maps API documentation and Stackoverflow for an answer, unfortunately I'm not a JavaScript guru. They all seem to be implemented in a different way and I have not been successful in making it work. The closest I've come, is removing one marker.

I appreciate any help provided, Thanks!!

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.680099,-73.945693),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

var markerShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
    new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

var restaurantColor = "0080FF";

var restaurantMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + restaurantColor,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

var takeoutColor = "79CEFF";

var takeoutMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + takeoutColor,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

$('#category').change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'restaurant') {

        for (i = 0; i < restaurant.length; i++) {
            marker = []
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(restaurant[i][1], restaurant[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: restaurantMarker,
            shadow: markerShadow,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(restaurant[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
          })(marker, i));
        }
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 'takeout') {

        for (i = 0; i < takeout.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(takeout[i][1], takeout[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: takeoutMarker,
            shadow: markerShadow,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(takeout[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
          })(marker, i));
        }

    }

});

var restaurant = [
    ['<div class="restaurant"><strong>SoCo Southern Comfort</strong><br />509 Myrtle Ave. Brooklyn, NY 11205<br /> <a href="tel://718-783-1936">(718) 783-1936</a></div>', 40.693846,-73.964513, 1],

    ['<div class="restaurant"><strong>Black Swan</strong><br />1048 Bedford Ave. Brooklyn, NY 11205<br /><a href="tel://718-783-4744">(718) 783-4744</a></div>', 40.689128,-73.955187, 2]
];

var takeout = [
    ['<div class="take_out"><strong>Chan&#39;s Garden</strong><br />679 Myrtle Ave. Brooklyn, NY 11205<br /><a href="tel://718-875-6637">(718) 875-6637</a></div>', 40.694729,-73.956357, 1],

    ['<div class="take_out"><strong>New Hardee Chinese Restaurant</strong><br />835 DeKalb Ave. Brooklyn, NY 11221<br /><a href="tel://718-384-0338">(718) 384-0338</a></div>', 40.692559,-73.943021, 2]
];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3 - Remove all Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526717/google-maps-v3-remove-all-markers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3: How to remove all markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the documentation and it seems that the marker method .setMap(null) (Notice the null parameter) will remove the marker. Did you try this already ?

You said you already had removed a marker. How did you do this?

Comment: Hi Marky, thanks for the response. I did try the .setMap(null), but I don't think I did it correctly though b/c it kept preventing new location markers from being drawn...they looked like they were begining to drop on the map, but never did. Only once I managed to remove one marker, but unfortunately I don't remember how I got there right now.

Comment: I'm inlined to think it has something to do with my arrays all being different names (restaurant, takeout)..not sure though. Do you think you could show me how you would go about declaring it? I would greatly appreciate the help. Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I am not able to get to the code at the moment to see how I fixed it, however I remember an interim solution I had was to redraw the map, not ideal but may help, will try and get the full solution though

Comment: I've though about this, but the map redraw seems a bit more distracting not to mention slower. So if I can manage to clear the markers that would be ideal. When you happen to have some time and be near your code, if you could share your solution that would be awesome. I greatly appreciate your help. Happy Holidays!